# Python filtering for numeric and string in a single data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame where a single column `Value` has strings.  Some of these string values are numeric.  I realize that since they are in the same column these are both treated as strings, but I need to differentiate between those that are actually strings and those that are actually numeric.

I want to create two additional columns called `Value_Num` and `Value_Txt` then drop the original `Value` column.

I had a script running that used the following command:

```
df['Value_Num'] = df.Value.convert_objects(convert_numeric=true)
```

That worked perfectly. However, in transitioning to a newer version I get this error:

> FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated. Use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.

I can't figure out how to rewrite my command with that `pd.to_numeric` function.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the docs? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the `FutureWarning` issued by `convert_objects`,  you could use [`pd.numeric` with `errors='coerce'`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Value'], errors='coerce')
```

This sets non-numeric strings to `NaN` -- exactly what we want for `Value_Num`.

We can then use `pd.notnull` to identify the rows in `Value_Num` with non-NaN values and set these rows to `NaN` in the `Value` column. Thus the `Value` column obtains the values  we want for the `Value_Txt` column. Renaming `Value` to `Value_Txt` completes the task:

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':['1', 'foo', '1.23', 'bar', '3.14e6']})
df['Value_Num'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'], errors='coerce')
mask = pd.notnull(df['Value_Num'])
df.loc[mask, 'Value'] = np.nan
df = df.rename(columns={'Value':'Value_Txt'})
print(df)
```

yields

```
    Value   Value_Num   type
0       1        1.00  False
1    1.23        1.23  False
2     foo         NaN   True
3  3.14e6  3140000.00  False
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want...unfortunately it didn't work.  All values end up in the Value_Txt column and the Value_Num column is NaN for everything.

The isnumeric function returns False for every value.

Comment: That would happen if the `Value` column contained actual numeric values (e.g. `123`), not *numeric strings* (e.g. `'123'`). Is that the case? Use `df['type'] = df['Value'].str.isnumeric()` *before* calling `to_numeric`.

Comment: Hmm, the problem could also occur if the numeric strings contain a decimal point. Working on a fix....

Comment: I've edited the post above with a different suggestion.

Comment: I'm running through my processes now, but I think that worked. Huge thanks.

What's the deal with the decimals?  Why aren't those recognized as numeric?  Is it just because numeric looks to integers as opposed to floats?

Comment: The Pandas `Series.str.isnumeric` method calls the Python [`str.isnumeric`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) method. This merely tests that each character in the string is a numeric character. Unfortunately, characters like `.` and `e` which may appear in float string representations are not considered numeric characters.
Because if this difficulty, I thought it might be better to use `errors='coerce'` and `pd.notnull` to identify the (non)numeric strings.